# copy data from one table to another @mysql database every 5 secs

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Hello Everyone,
              I am building up a webpage using asp.net which will populate data from a table@ my sql database. I need to copy data from one table to another for history purpose every 5 secs.
My question: how can I implement a sql script which will run continuously on server, check and insert data  from one table to another so that my webpage will refresh latest data every 5 secs? Also, is it possible to implement using asp.net only even if webpage is not opened?

This is my 1st  web project so please bear with me. Responses are highly appreciated!

Comment: you can use trigger or schedule a job for sql query to run.

Comment: Why not display the data directly from the original table, without copying it to the second one? Data duplication is really something to avoid whenever possible (and I'm not seeing a compelling reason based on the description here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through this link to schedule an event 
 [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Some useful links
[mySQL daily backup from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485506/mysql-daily-backup-from-one-table-to-another)

### Edit -1

But the best will be using trigger for your table.
Example

[MySQL trigger On Insert/Update events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events)

Answer (score 0):

Here are one of the few things u can do:

1. Create a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) of the original table in the database you want the data to be accessible.
2. Create a [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) as Shekhar has suggested.
3. Write a cron job which picks values from one table and inserts it in another. U can do this on the basis of creation_time/updation_time and you will need to handle duplication.

Solution 1&2 will work only when both the databases are on same mysql server while 3 will work otherwise as well.

Comment: I wrote a trigger but it is only validating for one cell of the column instead of entire column. My question: If value of the column changes to particular value eg: Status= 'Start' Or Status= Pause how can I write a trigger which will copy entire row to another table? Please shar the example if possible. You guys have nbeen kind. Thank you so much! Can I mark multiple answers correct?

Comment: can you please post the trigger definition for us to see... to handle updates you can use `after update` triggers... definition would somewhat look like `CREATE TRIGGER after_table_update
AFTER UPDATE ON table_test FOR EACH ROW target_table_test SET  a=NEW.a, b=NEW.b...`.. but you will have to different multiple trigger definitions for insert and update... while if u use views, one definition would suffice.