# Problem with sql schedule table and preserving old data using JOIN

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to sql, so forgive me if there's a simple answer. I'm setting up a scheduling database for lessons in a school. Each class has between 3 and 9 students. I was originally planning to use two tables with a JOIN as follows:

Table 1:   Class  Day-of-week  Start-time End-time  Student1 ... Student9

JOIN

Table 2:   Date   Class  Teacher

This would give a list of all the classes by date. The problem is that if a new student joins the class, updating Table 1 would add that student to all the previous rows although the student didn't attend those classes. Is there a better (and simple) way to set up the schedule which preserves the data in past rows?

*edit It's not so much a problem with the code, but more of a data organization problem. (I've included the code I'm using below).

Table 1:   Class  Day-of-week  Start-time End-time  S1   S2  S3... S9

```
       English  Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue  Null....Null
```

Table 2:   Date        Class   Teacher

```
      2019-01-07  English   ProfX   
      2019-01-14  English   ProfY
      2019-01-21  English   ProfZ
```

Then the JOIN looks like

Schedule

```
2019-01-07  English   ProfX   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue  Null....Null
2019-01-14  English   ProfY   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue  Null....Null
2019-01-21  English   ProfZ   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue  Null....Null
```

Now assume a new student (Tim) joins for the next class. If I update Table 1 with the new student, all of the previous rows would include Tim, but he wasn't in the class for 2019-01-07 or 2019-01-14, so my table would look like this.

```
2019-01-07  English   ProfX   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue Tim....Null
2019-01-14  English   ProfY   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue Tim....Null
2019-01-21  English   ProfZ   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue Tim....Null
```

When I only want this:

```
2019-01-07  English   ProfX   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue  Null....Null
2019-01-14  English   ProfY   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue  Null....Null
2019-01-21  English   ProfZ   Mon        8:00       9:00      Jon Sue Tim....Null
```

////code////

```
Create VIEW 'schedule' SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON (Table1.class = Table2.class);
```

Comment: If you could share the sample data, that would be helpful to solve it.

Comment: It's a simple VIEW and JOIN. I added the code and a little more clarification to the problem.

Comment: Are you adding Tim to the same column with Jon Sue as a comma separated value? Or adding Tim to a new column? anyway non of this is a good practice.

Comment: @IMS Student1 through Student9 are 9 different columns. This approach seems simple and appropriate for my application. Please recommend a better approach if you know one.

Comment: You can have a separate Student table to keep student details (Student id, Student Name). And in Table 1 you can have ID, Day-of-week, Start-time, End-time. And you can have a mapping table to map student id to Table 1 ID.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest approach is to schedule a daily copy of the final table without rewriting existing rows.

[mySQL daily backup from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485506/mysql-daily-backup-from-one-table-to-another)

[MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday)